Balancing demographic effects of different reproductive strategies
I am building a world with two sapient species, one of which is effectively equivalent to humans, and another one which has a series of differences. I would like to know how to tweak the numerical values relating to their reproduction and aging to make sure that both species are about equal in terms of population sustainability, spread,  replacement, and the like. That is, I would like the ratio of two species in a setting to start out approximately equal, and stay approximately equal over the course of millennia (though local imbalances are fine if overall they even out in a mostly Terra-like set of biomes).
The peculiarities of the nonhuman species' reproduction include the following:

Upon dying and being left on/in the ground, their bodies turn into a tree-like plant. I'm open to letting the trees have supernatural benefits when it comes to growth, but I'd rather have them at least be in line with conservation of mass. Such a grave-tree can grow either in a cultivated grave-garden, or in the wilderness if that is where the body was left.
The fruit of those trees are the children. If grown in an area with adults around, the children gain sapience before detaching from the tree, and thus undergo some of their upbringing/education before becoming ambulatory. If grown in the wilderness, they detach early and start their life in a beastly manner.
I'm inclined to grant both origins a much improved neuroplasticity and ability to learn very very quickly in the early part of life (and reach adulthood or at least adolescence very fast) to compensate for the disadvantages of a sessile start of life and the feral lack of education. I'm inclined to give wild-borns even greater neuroplasticity to catch up fast.
A single tree may give birth to multiple children, of course.
The tree/child inherits some mixture of traits from the primary (i.e. dead) parent and from all the parent's partners throughout life.

Obviously, a sessile beginning of life is a great disadvantage when it comes to speed of a demographic spreading. How should I tweak some of the numbers relating to reproduction to make this species stand on approximately equal ground with humans? Numbers that come to mind:

Time taken from death to the fruit reaching adolescence and awakening.
Time taken for the child in a cultivated grave-garden to be educated into a proximity of adolescence and separate from the tree.
Typical time taken for a wild-born beast-child (which starts out with some besatly adaptations for living without tools, hunting &c.) to catch up to socialisation and education upon meeting adults. (Assume the child is instinctively friendly towards adults of the species, and that communities are usually eager to adopt wild children if they can afford to.)
Typical time between fruits maturing / frequency of fruit-bearing.
Typical maximum duration a tree remains fertile after bearing the first fruit, or a range of such durations.

Note that while I'm willing to play somewhat loose with what's biologically plausible, I don't want to jump too deep into allowing the impossible unless it's necessary.

How do you apply conservation of mass to a body turning into a tree?

In the sense that it needs to get those molecules somewhere - from the soil, from the remains of the body and the like, like plants (and fungi) normally do.

(a) I've always liked the idea of plant-based humanoid reproduction. I first encountered it in Edgar Rice Burroughs' Barsoom series. (b) I like how you've defined the non-human species. (c) However... I'm having trouble understanding what problem you have. Knowing what dials to turn is 90% of the battle and you already have that. Can you [edit] your post to explain in more detail exactly what it is you need from us and what metrics would define a successful answer?

@JBH I know what dials I want to 'play' with, but I'm no mathematician and no demographer. I don't know what values to set on those dials.

How gruesome are you prepared to go? (Gollum: "Is it nice,my preciousss? Is it juicy? Is it scrumptiously crunchable?")

A few questions jump out:  If you look a human demographic trends, they change massively as a result of changes in society, trade and technology.  Are you looking at a period of millenia with no significant changes, or are you looking for a way to keep the tree people level-pegging as the human demographics change?  Is there any motive for humans and tree people to co-exist rather than one try to conquer/exterminate the other?

" get those molecules somewhere - from the soil" Plants get the vast majority of their matter from the atmosphere, not the soil.

I am not sure what the expected answer is. One possible expected answer would be a link to the free-to-use Web-based variant of Excel, or to Google Sheets, or possibly a link from where to download LibreOffice Calc. Or maybe the question is expecting somebody to actually build a worksheet and provide it free of charge; but this won't do, because this kind of professional services are almost always provided on a commercial basis. Voting to close as definitely not about worldbuilding, but rather about how to avoid paying for the development of a numerical model.

A key issue is the death rate. Human population explosion is more a matter of reduced death rate than increased birth rate. Trees have to deal with insect induced mortality as well as drought and fire. Much of the Great Plains would have trees on them if they didn't have fires every 4-20 years. How vulnerable are these while in tree format - both as juveniles and as adults as that might be different?

I think there's a valid worldbuilding question here, but there's a lot of confusion about your goals. The fact that you've not edited your quesiton to clarify those goals is a bad sign. What, specifically, are you trying to do? Be very, very, very specific. I'm personally worried that you've trapped yourself in the proverbial rabbit hole. In most instances, specific numbers on those dials don't matter. The existence of the dials (to the story reader) justifies a condition of your world, which you've not defined very well. Odds are you don't need numbers, just the dials.

BTW, please note that closing quesitons is what Stack Exchange expects the community to do so the question has a chance to be clarified and improved before potentially useless answers arrive. We're all happy to retract our votes, we just need the clarifications. Do you really need specific numbers? Why? What one, single target or goal are you trying to match? Thanks.

This is a problem of resource availability and - if the populations are in conflict for scarce resources in the same habitat - relative survival fitness. You don't actually need to know the things you listed - although the remaining problem of how resources stay equally available for thousands of years may be even harder to solve without resorting to extreme amounts of luck or alien/divine intervention.
